# Browser extension to upload several images at once in an answer or question on Stack Exchange

Tags: web-browser, images, stack-exchange

I'm looking for a browser extension that can:

- upload several images at once in an answer or question on Stack Exchange

And if possible:

- works on Windows 7 + Google Chrome
- free

Comment: Have you considered posting a feature request on [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?